# C++ use method in a struct member

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new in C++ programming, and I've got this situation. I have a struct which is defined like this

```
struct someStruct{
    ...
    char sType[16];
    ...
};
```

In my code I try to compare which value comes into this member, and I try to use something like this (because I worked in C#)

```
someStruct.sType.compare("FF") == 0
```

but it throws a compilation error. What I'm doing now is asign someStruct.sType to a variable X and use

```
X.compare
```

Is this the way to do this? (I don't think so) 
Is there another way to acomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A char array is not a class, therefore it has no member functions such as `compare`.

You could use [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) instead:

```
std::string sType;
```

And compare it with [`std::string::compare`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/):

```
if (someStruct.sType.compare("FF") == 0)
```

Or simply using [`operator==`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/):

```
if (someStruct.sType == "FF")
```

Comment: `if (someStruct.sType == "FF")` does not do what you imply it does; it does not compare the contents of the char[], it compares the addresses of the arrays.

Comment: @MikeC I'm talking about `std::string` here, not char arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).  It has the methods you are looking for.  It even has a [`compare`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/) method.

A char array isn't an object with any methods associated with it, it's just data.